# What would be required to establish probable cause for an arrest and charge for obstruction of justice?

Tags: criminal-law, alcohol, obstruction

This question asked [is it legal to pretend to be drunk?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97358/is-it-legal-to-pretend-to-be-drunk/97360?noredirect=1#comment226347_97360)

A potential charge of obstruction of justice was suggested in one of the answers.

What would be required to meet a reasonable standard of probable cause to arrest someone and charge them for obstruction of justice if they stumbled a few times in a parking lot?

Bonus if you can describe evidence sufficient to bring a conviction, and/or criteria to bring a counter claim or charge of unlawful arrest.

Comment: common experience in the US is that the bar for probably cause for obstruction is virtually buried.

Comment: @TigerGuy, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @MichaelHall TigerGuy says that the probable cause is given by them stopping you for your act.

Comment: "obstruction and resisting" are blanket charges applied when cops don't like what you're doing.  Note that in the US, police have very broad arrest powers and there is very little the arrested person can do about it.

Comment: I did say "reasonable", and added a minor change in the body to match the title question about charging.  @trish, I don't understand your point. Are you saying that the police stopping someone for any reason constitutes probable cause for obstruction of justice?

Comment: @MichaelHall no, but if you expose that you *deliberately* lead them to stop you, then they have.

Comment: @Trish, see my comment to Jen on the other question...  There is nothing in my question, or the other one, stating that it is revealed to the police that you *deliberately* lead them to stop you.

Comment: **"We drew lots, and I was the bait"** - that's admission of deliberate bad behavior.

Comment: @trish, that quote was in the joke that spawned the question. Please read it again, the question states clearly: "*Assume that **in this situation** the driver is smarter and does not say anything, so he **does not admit** trying to interfere with law enforcement.*"

Comment: Is it illegal to be drunk in a parking lot? Why would the police person care?

Comment: @NeilMeyer  The person isn't drunk.  Anyway, it was suggested that I ask a new question because of a similar remark I made on the other question.